# Android Studio use SVN to Commit Multiple Modules

Tags: android, android-studio, svn, module, commit

I used to use SVN in Eclipse and develop Android, but now I have to use **Android Studio with SVN**, but I don't know how to commit multiple module (because my app contains many libraries which I'm not sure if I should commit all these library?)

Maybe I should commit these library one by one?

Comment: maybe, ive googled and couldnt find something useful... one parallel tip: move to git ;)

Answer (score 1):

Commit what's logical to group together. If you have changes to multiple modules that are part of a single change to your application, make a single commit. If they're independent, multiple commits may make more sense.

If you want to commit multiple modules at once, you must do so from a common working copy root directory **and** they must all exist in the same repository.

Comment: Thanks ,I'll try this.And now I get another question about using library's activities in app , should I register these activities in app's manifest.xml?

Comment: If you have a new question, you need to post it as such - not a comment on an unrelated question.